# Use key navigation script on more than one page

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am trying to do something like pressing keys A and H opens home page. That is the user has to press the H key on holding the A key. I want this event to be occurred across all the website not in a single page.

I came with a jQuery approach as below

```
var down = {};
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    down[e.keyCode] = true;
}).keydown(function(e) {
      if (down[65] && down[72]) {
      // logic to go to my home page
      }
});​
```

When i implemented the above script in a single jsp page, it works fine. How can i make my script listen across all the web pages.

Comment: You just need to add that piece of JS code to all the pages you want it to work in.

Comment: You can't make it work across all the web pages since you can't access their code. You can make an addon like greasemonkey or smth.

Comment: Yes, it works when i place the code across all the web pages. Also it works when i use any common header/footer section and place my script in that jsp. Can we do it in a way like placing in a common .js file.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a common header/footer sections for all pages or at least a common template.
Add the crucial **js** code into the common template to make it work on all pages. Avoid duplicating same code on each page.